# Running Azure policy evaluation on demand getting the error Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-policy

I am trying to run Azure policy evaluation on demand. According to the documentation, there is an API that can be used to trigger this, and a Ps script. I have opted for the API since I have got 8 subscriptions and much easier to invoke the API at the subscription level.

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object Name -eq 'xxx'

foreach($subscription in $subscriptions){
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription

    $SubscriptionId = $subscription.Id

    $azContext = Get-AzContext
    $azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    $profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azProfile)
    $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($azContext.Subscription.TenantId)

    $authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application/json'
        'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $token.AccessToken
    }

    $restUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/triggerEvaluation?api-version=2018-07-01-preview"
       
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUrl -Method POST -Headers $authHeader

}
```

I then get the error below.

`Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.At line:1 char:1+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUrl -Method POST -Headers $authHeader + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`

Having done some research, I have ran the following.

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` to no avail.

Comment: Post indicates your HTTP Request has a body.  You do not have a body.  You are putting parameters in the header.  Try using the code at following : https://blog.simonw.se/getting-an-access-token-for-azuread-using-powershell-and-device-login-flow/

Comment: I think the equivalent azure Powershell cmdlet is ```Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan``` - have you tried that instead? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/start-azpolicycompliancescan?view=azps-11.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

The above error is encountered because of passing the wrong `Uri`. The parameter mentioned in the code is `$restUri`, but in the `Invoke-RestMethod` command, you are passing `$restUrl`. If you still encounter the same issue, kindly update the `PowerShell` module to the latest version.

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to trigger evaluations.

```
    $subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object Name -eq 'xxxxxxxx'
    
    foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
        Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
    
        $SubscriptionId = $subscription.Id
    
        $newtoken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com"
        $authHeader = @{
            'Content-Type'='application/json'
            'Authorization'='Bearer ' + $newtoken.Token
        }
    
        $restUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/triggerEvaluation?api-version=2018-07-01-preview"
    
        try {
            # Try to invoke the REST method
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUri -Method POST -Headers $authHeader
    
            # If successful, print a success message
            Write-Host "Policy evaluation triggered successfully for subscription: $SubscriptionId"
        } catch {
            # If an error occurs, print the error message and status code
            Write-Host "Failed to trigger policy evaluation for subscription: $SubscriptionId. $_"
            if ($_.Exception.Response -ne $null) {
                $statusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
                Write-Host "Response code: $statusCode"
            }
        }
    }
```

**Response:**

[image]

Reference: [Trigger evaluations for all resources in a subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policy-states/trigger-subscription-evaluation?view=rest-policy-2019-10-01&tabs=HTTP#trigger-evaluations-for-all-resources-in-a-subscription)